# Sampling RBM with clamped visible nodes (reconstruction with partial information)

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am playing around with Restricted Boltzmann Machines, and I am interested in the generation of new samples. More precisely, I am interested in the problem of reconstructing samples when partial information about them is known. This means that I have some visible nodes which I would like to have fixed during the sampling procedure, so I obtain a sample that has a high $p(v_{all-y}|v_y)$. However, in RBMs we know that $p(v)=\prod_ip(v_i)$, which in particular means that $p(v_{all-y}|v_y)=p(v_{all-y})$.

I have done some tests nevertheless. I have implemented some sort of "clamping" by fixing the visible nodes in $y$ to the desired values, sampling the hidden layer, sampling the visible layer from the hidden, and changing the values of the nodes in $y$ to the desired ones, repeating the procedure until convergence. This shows some satisfactory results, but given that the number of nodes in $y$ is typically much smaller than the total amount of visible nodes, it is not strange that I converge to other samples that do not have to do with the initial data from which I wanted to reconstruct a sample because of the random initialization of the rest of the nodes.

My question therefore is: how are Restricted Boltzmann Machines actually used to perform sample reconstruction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does RBM mean?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It refers to Restricted Boltzmann Machines https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_Boltzmann_machine. I have edited the question to make it clearer.